# Sequel first and get?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Hello I have built the following query:

```
patron.where.first(:Queued => 1)
```

This returns the entire record, I just need one column named `time`. Something like:

```
patron.where.first(:Queued => 1).get(:time)
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
patron.where(:Queued => 1).select(:time).first
```

Comment: @Jason Price, I've edited it, but I'm going off http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/active_record_rdoc.html since I'm more familiar with ActiveRecord so my apologies if this doesn't work either.  Just to be clear, your Sequel model is called `patron`, and its associated table has a field `Queued`?  I ask because I'd expect the capitalization to be the other way around.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - It was an oversight on my part when I first generated the tables. Also the code offered again provided no joy. Thanks for trying I have been banging my head over this for hours.

Comment: Ah ha! The above code returned; `{:time=>"t4"}`, anyway to return just the t4?

Comment: For anyone else new to ruby it is a hash and to get the data you use: hashName[:time]